# How do we diagnose delays After large number of files are deleted?

Tags: kernel, filesystem, performance, logs, inode

This one needs a Linux/Ubuntu guru.

A runaway program generated a large number (at least a million?) of files into /var/log. Even after deleting all (?) rogue files, any query on the folder/tree now takes about 5 minutes, and can cause the whole system to be sluggish.

The issue was that .gz files created by logrotate were being added to other .gz archives, and those were being archived and ... oops. So all invalid .gz files have been deleted from /var/log - the source issue has been fixed.

How can I find out exactly what is still causing delays?

- In the /var/log tree there are 75 directories with 1606 files, consuming only 1GB.
- `ls /var/log` takes over 5 minutes to process.
- Other larger folder trees take much less time to query with `ls`, `find`, `grep`, etc.
- `tree` on /var/log also takes about 5 minutes and the result is a completely normal folder/file tree.
- `df -i` shows a total of 10 million inodes, less than a million used, over 9 million unused. The system has been rebooted several times.

I would be OK with `rm -rf` on the entire log tree followed by a restart. With `mv` or `cp` to a different folder, "some reset", and moving everything back, I would be concerned that I would just be copying the problem from one place to another.

I'm wondering if we can scan/cleanse for corrupted inodes, or maybe if it would help to reduce the number of inodes down to a minimum and then kick it back up after a restart.

It's a simple installation with /var in the one and only / root partition for OS/data. So unmounting/replacement is not an option.

I can easily run diagnostics and provide relevant info.

This is a fully patched v20.04.3 cloud server. I can open a console if required.

`e4defrag` did not show fragmentation. May run `fsck` (`e2fsck` or `shutdown -rF`) if that is advised. These are examples of the kinds of utilities I'm seeking to help with diagnostics for this kind of issue.

---

EDIT 10 months later: Still need help to diagnose this ongoing issue.

- I now have two systems in a similar state due to the same rogue script, now permanently fixed.
- Memory is not stressed: RAM Used/Total=2/4GB, Added Swap, 1/4GB
- ls without '.' folder on /var/log shows 48k blocks, but 'ls -la' shows over 800 blocks, the '.' alias shows 750MB
- `du` on /var/log shows about 1.2GB, very little difference with --apparent-size.
- Auto-completion of names is also significantly delayed, as expected.
- Aside from a few normal 'journal' files up to the 80M range, there are no unusually large files.
- After doing several directory accesses in a row it goes much faster. This seems to indicate caching. RAM/Swap usage doesn't change much during this time.

Once every few days, this system will throw lockup warnings:

> kernel [0.0] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 59s! [process:0]

Sometimes that will force a disconnect/termination of whatever random process was stuck.

Because of these issues I'm planning a re-installation, like we need to do with Windows every couple years. But I'd really like to know how to diagnose these issues ... and do so here so that everyone can learn how this works.

Comment: Is it OK to reboot the computer?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and which file system are you using? Deleting and recreating the log directory is an option, but will need to be done via a live session as some directories cannot be deleted while the OS is running.

Comment: Added OS version = fully patched 20.04.3. Deleting and recreating the log directory is an option. But as a technician I'm more interested in understanding why this is happening before nuking away the symptoms. :) If we understand the problem, and how to diagnose the problem, then others who see this will be better educated and better able to deal with similar issues.

Note from above, system has been restarted many times.

Comment: I haven't resolved this issue and now have two systems in the same state. Adding more detail to OP.