# How do we properly clear and refresh /var/log?

Tags: filesystem, logs

I have two v20.04 systems where a script created, literally, a million files in /var/log. After removing the junk (and fixing the script) access to that directory has been very slow for many months. [I have tried unsuccessfully to diagnose and fix that problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1363042/how-do-we-diagnose-delays-after-large-number-of-files-are-deleted).

Before doing a complete reinstall, I'd like to try doing a clean refresh of /var/log. This Q&A is intended to document the proper, cleanest, fastest way to replace the entire /var/log directory, with as little disruption as possible. Yes, I can experiment in a new system to see what seems to work, but that doesn't tell me the 'proper' way to avoid long-term unforeseen consequences.

**Approach 1: Delete anything in the directory**

I do not want to `rm -rf /var/log/*` because a similar operation has already left these systems in a weird state.

Maybe this is old info, but I've read that we shouldn't simply delete /var/log files, because they may not get re-created on a shutdown/restart. Can anyone verify or correct this for Ubuntu v20+? I suspect this is dependent on each application and whether they assume that after initial creation that their logs will always exist, or if they always write as create/append.

**Approach 2: Replace the entire directory**

- init s
- mv /var/log /var/oldlogs
- mkdir -p /var/log
- chown root:syslog /var/log
- chmod 0775 /var/log
- init 6

That might not be possible due to file locks. It might cause momentary (inconsequential?) errors in something that might still be running in maintenance mode. The folder might be locked by some permissions that prevent its removal. How can we be sure that the above will work?

Again, as above, we need to be sure that on restart the expected files are created when they do not exist.

**Approach 3: clear and replace known files**

This requires manual effort that should be scripted and will vary per-system. The idea is to clear everything as above, but before restart, copy back in specific folders and files that are known to be required and uncorrupted. This will help to eliminate the noted potential problems with expected files and directories.

**Approach 4: Longer-term solution: Mount (bind) a new directory**

Similar to approach 2, but rather than allowing new logs to be created directly in /var/log, mount that to a completely different folder, like /var/local/logs.

**Approach 5: Longer-term solution: Use a different partition for logs**

Rebuild the system, create a separate partition for logs, and mount that to /var/logs.

**Summary**

Given the above options that I've considered, I'm hoping someone will confirm one of the above as the most effective and trouble-free solution, or propose something different that everyone finding this Q&A can use. The 'right' solution would be something that we know we can do as a part of normal system maintenance. I have no idea if there might be a utility already built-in to Ubuntu that rebuilds /var/log, live or on restart, or maybe some utility/gist on Github.

Comment: What filesystem type (`df -T /var/log`) does it use?  Possibly the directory needs to be shrunk, I'm not sure how to do that without replacing it.

Comment: As long as you don't move files across filesystems, moving the files in /var/log to a new /var/log shouldn't break any locks or open files.  There might be a race condition for creating new ones though.

Comment: Thanks for your responses so far. For these systems there is a single ext4 filesystem mounted on a single /dev/vda1 volume.

Comment: Duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/264124/shrink-reset-directory-size although I don't like the cp solution in one of those answers, your mv is better.

Comment: I house clean old logs as part of an update & houseclean script. `find /var/log/ -name *.gz* -type f -atime +10 -print -exec rm -f {} +` If I have not noticed an issue for 10 days, I figure it does not matter or will be shown in recent files. But I typically use system every day.  Does not delete current logs & some are not .gz but just .1 or .2 etc.

Comment: Normally, logrotate would take care of that, but I think this situation is exceptional and outside the scope of logrotate.

Comment: Thanks again so far, but you guys have missed details: "After removing the junk (and fixing the script) access to that directory has been very slow for many months." The link that follows that details a corrupted file system that resulted from rm of a million files. Also: "I do not want to rm -rf /var/log/* because a similar operation has already left these systems in a weird state." The file system is corrupt. I need to replace it, not just remove files or logrotate. Thanks. (OOPS: @user10489 is correct that this sitaution is exceptional) I'm going through the shrink link/notes.

Comment: It's not corrupted.  The problem is that the directory has extra blocks and is probably very sparse.  The `fsck -D` option in the duplicate above should fix it completely.  The `mv` solutions should also work but they have their own issues.

Comment: We're making progress. I accept (with gratitude) that there's no corruption, that /var/log needs to be defragged. I will pursue that. I could be wrong, but I think it would still be helpful to get solid documentation here on how to clear /var/log in modern Ubuntu. I disagree that this is a duplicate: This question is about ext4 with a modern OS. While a similar question was asked for older platforms, the answers for those platforms don't seem to apply. This question, specifically about how to process /var/log, which has special considerations, needs a current and specific answer.